# How to generate new variables based on the name of the variables in the data frame

Tags: r, vectorization

For example, I have a toy dataset as the one I created below,

```
 a1<-1:10
 a2<-11:20
 v<-c(1,2,1,NA,2,1,2,1,2,1)
 data<-data.frame(a1,a2,v,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then I want to create a new variable `y` which will be assigned the value `a1` or `a2` or `NA` based on the value of variable `v`. Therefore, the 'y' 
should equals to `1 12  3 NA 15  6 17  8 19 10`.

I want to generate it with the command similar to the ones I list below, It doesn't work, I guess it's because of the vectorization issue, then how can I fix it?

In reality, I have several `a`s, say 10 and the actual values are characters instead of numeric ones.

```
 data$y[!is.na(data$v)]<-data[,paste0('a',data$v)]
```

or

```
 data%>%
 mutate(y=ifelse(!is.na(v),get(paste0('a',v)),NA))
```

Comment: @ Marco Sandri What if we use `mutate` here?

Comment: @ Marco Sandri neat, what if a1 and a2 are characters, rather than numeric value and it has a1 to a5 (5 variables)? That's the reason I try the `paste` here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use standard indexing with `cbind` for that:

```
dat$y <- dat[cbind(1:nrow(dat), dat$v)]
```

The result:

```
> dat
   a1 a2  v  y
1   1 11  1  1
2   2 12  2 12
3   3 13  1  3
4   4 14 NA NA
5   5 15  2 15
6   6 16  1  6
7   7 17  2 17
8   8 18  1  8
9   9 19  2 19
10 10 20  1 10
```

(I used `dat` instead of `data`, because it is not wise to call a dataframe the same as a function; see `?data`)

Answer (score 1):

Only idea that comes to my mind:

```
 data%>%
       mutate(y=ifelse(!is.na(v),paste0('a',v),NA)) %>%
       mutate(z=ifelse(!is.na(y),(ifelse(y=="a1",get("a1"),get("a2"))),NA))

   a1 a2  v    y  z
1   1 11  1   a1  1
2   2 12  2   a2 12
3   3 13  1   a1  3
4   4 14 NA <NA> NA
5   5 15  2   a2 15
6   6 16  1   a1  6
7   7 17  2   a2 17
8   8 18  1   a1  8
9   9 19  2   a2 19
10 10 20  1   a1 10
```

or more directly:

```
data%>%
   mutate(y=ifelse(!is.na(v),(ifelse(v==1, get("a1"),get("a2"))),NA))

   a1 a2  v  y
1   1 11  1  1
2   2 12  2 12
3   3 13  1  3
4   4 14 NA NA
5   5 15  2 15
6   6 16  1  6
7   7 17  2 17
8   8 18  1  8
9   9 19  2 19
10 10 20  1 10
```

still based on ifelse :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a matrix accessor:

```
# Get the indices of missing values
ind <- which(!is.na(data$v))
# Transform colnames to indices
tab <- structure(match(c("a1", "a2"), names(data)), .Names = c("a1", "a2"))
# Access data with a matrix accessor
data$y[ind] <- data[cbind(ind, tab[paste0('a', data$v[ind])])]
```